# Is it ok to change implementation of parent function with child data?

Tags: php, object-oriented, html, inheritance

I was wondering is it OK to change implementation of parent class with child class data. I have situation of creating a child class (form) which extends the parent class (other form with same elements). If I don't change implementation of parent class some HTML Elements will have the same id and both forms are on same page. So I am not sure if this legitimate way in terms of OOP rules. I was wondering why to inherit parent class when I want to change it?!

```
public function __construct(AddTaskErrors $addTaskErrors=null,
childData = []) 
{
$this->addTaskErrors = $addTaskErrors;
$this->childData = $childData;

}    
public function build(array $predefinedValues = [])
{//name id label value  type za input
    //input
    $addTask = (isset($this->childData[self::ADD_TASK])) ? $this->childData[self::ADD_TASK] : self::ADD_TASK ;
    $this->addElement(new InputTextElement(
            $addTask , 
            $addTask , 
            $addTask , 
            '', 'text', $predefinedValues));

    $addTaskDeadline = (isset($this->childData[self::ADD_TASK_DEADLINE])) ? $this->childData[self::ADD_TASK_DEADLINE] : self::ADD_TASK_DEADLINE ;
    $this->addElement(new InputTextElement(
            $addTaskDeadline, 
            $addTaskDeadline, 
            $addTaskDeadline, 
            '', 'text', $predefinedValues));

    //select
    $addTaskPriority = (isset($this->childData[self::ADD_TASK_PRIORITY])) ? $this->childData[self::ADD_TASK_PRIORITY] : self::ADD_TASK_PRIORITY ;
    $this->addElement(new SelectElement(
            $addTaskPriority, 
            $addTaskPriority, 
            $addTaskPriority, 
            PriorityType::createFromDefaultValue(), $predefinedValues ));

    return $this->getElements();
}
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comments are within multi-line comments in the code block below.

```
/*
It makes no sense to try to enforce that an AddTaskErrors object be passed
only then to have a default null value.  Similarly, you should consider
type hinting the second parameter as array.  Force the caller to give
you the proper dependencies
*/
public function __construct(AddTaskErrors $addTaskErrors=null,
childData = []) 
{
/*
Indent your code here
*/
$this->addTaskErrors = $addTaskErrors;
$this->childData = $childData;
/*
Unnecessary line here
*/

}
/*
Add empty line between method definitions.
It seems like there is a lot happening in this single method. Consider
refactoring into multiple methods.
*/   
public function build(array $predefinedValues = [])
{//name id label value  type za input
    //input
/*
This line of code is way too long and hard to read.  Consider dropping ternary
in favor of brackets that make this more readable.
In all these cases where you are conditionally "overriding" the
class constant of the parent class, I wonder why you simply don't
ACTUALLY override the class constant in the child class rather
than have some conditional logic in the class. It would seem to be
a much better behavior to simply define a new class constant value
in the child class ratherh than having to pass these around in some
"data" variable and have this conditional logic.
*/
    $addTask = (isset($this->childData[self::ADD_TASK])) ? $this->childData[self::ADD_TASK] : self::ADD_TASK ;
/*
Why does the the object being instantiated here take the same variable 3 times?
*/
    $this->addElement(new InputTextElement(
            $addTask , 
            $addTask , 
            $addTask , 
            '', 'text', $predefinedValues));
/*
ternary -> brackets?
*/
    $addTaskDeadline = (isset($this->childData[self::ADD_TASK_DEADLINE])) ? $this->childData[self::ADD_TASK_DEADLINE] : self::ADD_TASK_DEADLINE ;
/*
Why same variable passed 3 times?
*/
    $this->addElement(new InputTextElement(
            $addTaskDeadline, 
            $addTaskDeadline, 
            $addTaskDeadline, 
            '', 'text', $predefinedValues));

    //select
/*
ternary -> brackets?
*/
    $addTaskPriority = (isset($this->childData[self::ADD_TASK_PRIORITY])) ? $this->childData[self::ADD_TASK_PRIORITY] : self::ADD_TASK_PRIORITY ;
/*
same variable 3 times?
*/
    $this->addElement(new SelectElement(
            $addTaskPriority, 
            $addTaskPriority, 
            $addTaskPriority, 
            PriorityType::createFromDefaultValue(), $predefinedValues ));

    return $this->getElements();
}
```

Comment: Tnx. It was helpful :)